# Set the background of org-exported <code> blocks according to theme

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I export org-mode files quite often, and almost all of them have code in them. When I do export code, it ends up coloring the text depending on my theme, however, I switch between a dark theme and a light theme regularly. In the case of the light theme, the `<code>` blocks need to have a light background, and for a dark theme they need to have a dark background (otherwise I end up with light yellow text on a greyish background and it's unreadable).

I have to add this line for dark backgrounds:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>pre.src {background-color: #303030; color: #e5e5e5;}</style>
```

And then remember to remove it any time I switch to a light colored background

Is there a way I can automatically detect the background color of the current theme at export time and use it in the exported HTML's CSS?

**EDIT**

I'm going with Jordon's answer (thanks Jordon, you get the karma points!), however I wanted to post the solution I ended up adding to my code, since it was a slightly modified version of his answer:

```
(defun my/org-inline-css-hook (exporter)
  "Insert custom inline css to automatically set the
background of code to whatever theme I'm using's background"
  (when (eq exporter 'html)
    (let* ((my-pre-bg (face-background 'default))
           (my-pre-fg (face-foreground 'default)))
      (setq
       org-html-head-extra
       (concat
        org-html-head-extra
        (format "<style type=\"text/css\">\n pre.src {background-color: %s; color: %s;}</style>\n"
                my-pre-bg my-pre-fg))))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'my/org-inline-css-hook)
```

This sets not only the background color, but also the foreground color. It also appends the line to the existing `org-html-head-extra` setting so other HTML isn't overwritten accidentally. I've tested and this works great for me!

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but wouldn't it be better instead to always enforce the same theme when exporting? Or do you intentionally export with different themes?

Comment: @Malabarba the intent is to be able to export which whichever theme I am currently using and have the code be readable. Since many themes do not cleanly switch (even with `disable-theme`), I do not want to have to restart Emacs with a separate theme just to export HTML, which I do many times a day.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current setup already uses the theme's colors on the code blocks, and the problem you're having is that the theme's background is not used. If I got it wrong, please feel free to rollback the edit I made to your title.

Comment: @Malabarba my current setup does not specify the background color of code blocks (though I can hard-code a background color in the css if that would help). I would like the background color of the theme to be used for the org-mode code blocks. The new title works for me.

Comment: There are two problems with the above  solution.  First, colors like 'gray80' won't get translated correctly to CSS values, and won't get set.  Secondly, every time the export runs, the `org-html-head-extra` gets appended to, leading to unbounded growth, though functionality of the style won't be impaired.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I believe org can use [`htmlize`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) to automatically color your source code blocks according to your theme.

Alternatively.

Check out [http://definitelyaplug.b0.cx/post/custom-inlined-css-in-org-mode-html-export/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130817065759/http://definitelyaplug.b0.cx/post/custom-inlined-css-in-org-mode-html-export/). It has a great example of how to use the `org-export-before-processing-hook` to throw custom css onto an org document before an html export.

Here's the code in case the site goes down:

Here on an html export, org will look for a file called styles.css in the current directory or a default file in the .emacs.d directory and inject that css into the document. This is nice but not perfect for your use case.

```el
(defun my-org-inline-css-hook (exporter)
  "Insert custom inline css"
  (when (eq exporter 'html)
    (let* ((dir (ignore-errors (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
           (path (concat dir "style.css"))
           (homestyle (or (null dir) (null (file-exists-p path))))
           (final (if homestyle "~/.emacs.d/org-style.css" path)))
      (setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
      (setq org-html-head (concat
                           "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                           "<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n"
                           (with-temp-buffer
                             (insert-file-contents final)
                             (buffer-string))
                           "/*]]>*/-->\n"
                           "</style>\n")))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'my-org-inline-css-hook)
```

You can customize this in a few ways to make it work how you'd like.

One way would be to manually build the css based on your theme and insert that.

Here is a modified version that sets the background of `pre.src` to the hex value of the default faces :background property.

```el
(defun my-org-inline-css-hook (exporter)
  "Insert custom inline css"
  (when (eq exporter 'html)
    (let ((my-pre-bg (face-background 'default)))
      (setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
      (setq org-html-head
            (format "<style type=\"text/css\">\n pre.src { background-color: %s;}</style>\n" my-pre-bg)))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'my-org-inline-css-hook)
```

Comment: Thanks Jordon, this is great! I've update my original question with my slightly edited version, but you get the bounty and solution!