# How do I change Org's HTML code background?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, htmlize

Modifying Minted
[background](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)
is easy if my output from Org is LaTeX.

```
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=LightGray,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}
(code)
\end{minted}
```

Also, for Minted I [understand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374050/10169)
that I
"*have to set the background color [myself]. This is not the default because it is really printer unfriendly.*" That's just fine, as I need no printouts. But IIUC HTML export does not go through LaTeX. Org exports directly to HTML (is that right?).

How do I change Org's HTML code background?

As it is, the syntax highlighting is close to unreadable.
[image]

If I use the
[.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3512/28733)

```
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-background-color "black")

(defun my-org-inline-css-hook (exporter)
  "Insert custom inline css"
  (when (eq exporter 'html)
    (let ((my-pre-bg (face-background 'default)))
      (setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
      (setq org-html-head
            (format "<style type=\"text/css\">\n pre.src { background-color: %s;}</style>\n" my-pre-bg)))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'my-org-inline-css-hook)
```

the HTML code output does get a dark background, but other colors vanish. Do you see what is happening?

[image: dark bg]

Comment: The other colors probably get the default. You might try setting your css to `pre.src { background-color: %s; color: purple; }` to see if the other text turns purple. If it does, you could change those to white, or to `(face-foreground 'default)`

Comment: Well, for a lot of elements the foreground is black, so they disappear into the black background. You'll have to either change them or change the background to something other than black - a somewhat darker grey (#626262 seems to work OK) will set off the black foreground elements and also the lighter grey elements (like `print` and `range`) and make the rest pop.

Comment: Don't change your .emacs for this: adding `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> pre.src { background-color: #626262; }</style>` seems to work in the sense that code blocks are readable withouth anything hiding away in the background. See [CSS Support](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing amitp's and NickD's comments:

Do not modify your `.emacs` file. It's [sufficient](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html) to add

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> pre.src { background-color: black; color: white; }</style>
```

in your `.org` file.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with custom `css` instead to have more control of the html output
look'n'feel, including source code blocks.

This is relevant configuration of `org`:

```
  (setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil
        org-html-htmlize-output-type 'css)
  (setq org-html-style 
        (concat "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                (with-temp-buffer
                  (insert-file-contents (concat user-emacs-directory "org/org.css"))
                  (buffer-string))
                "</style>\n"))
```

Where default org css is not included and `htmlize` output would be pure `css`
you can style yourself.

Then with `org-html-style` you can include your own `css`, here I include (as in
read from file) `~/.config/emacs/org/org.css`.

The `org.css` contents should cover everything you care about, including the relevant `htmlize` css class names:

```
.org-src-container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f7f7f3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: .1em .5em;
    position: relative
}
/* highglighting */
.org-function-name {
    color: #af00af
}
.org-keyword {
    color: #005faf
}
.org-builtin {
    color: #870087
}
.org-string, .org-doc {
    color: #008700
}
.org-comment,
.org-comment-delimiter {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-style: italic;
}
.org-preprocessor {
    color: #008787
}
.org-type {
    color: #af5f00
}
.org-variable-name {
    color: #870087
}
.org-constant {
    color: #af0000
}
.org-warning {
    color: #ff8c00;
    font-weight: 700
}
.org-error {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700
}
.org-escape-glyph {
    color: #8700ff
}
```

Result might look like:

[image]

Comment: Neat idea to use this level of granularity! But whenever I attempted to adjust individual colors the result was an eye sore. A way to hook back on a palette of colors designed by someone who is actually capable of making them cohesive, or even not clash, is a lot easier.